# Post button without refreshing page

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie in coding and I need your expertise help.

This is my index.php codes

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center"><h1>Stamford Network</h1></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="textarea" name="text" placeholder="What's on your mind?" class="form-control" id="info" /> 
            <input type="button" name="post" value="Post" class="btn btn-primary" id="post" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h3>Hello, 
            <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> 
            </h3>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="login.php" role="button" >Logout</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
        <h4 id="display"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My .js code which link to the above index.php

```
window.onload = function() {
    var button = document.getElementById("post");
    button.addEventListener("click",
        function() {
            document.getElementById("display");

    });
}
```

Can anyone tell me how create a post and display it without refreshing the page. Simply just click on the Post button then the information should appear below the posting form. While the words in the textarea should be gone when the button is clicked.
Please only show me the javascript way

Comment: You have to use ajax in this case.

Comment: Can you give an example of how can I use ajax in it?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
var button = document.getElementById("post");
button.addEventListener("click",
    function() {
        //document.getElementById("display");
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = document.getElementById('info').value;
        document.getElementById("info").style.display = "none";
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: do you want to hide textarea on clicking post btton??? clear total logic exactly what you expect.

Comment: Yup, that is what I expect

Answer (score 0):

```
var button = document.getElementById('post'),
    info = document.getElementById('info'),
    display = document.getElementById('display');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    display.innerText = info.value;
    info.value = '';
});
```

If you want the value to be uploaded to server for processing, you will need to add ajax `XMLHttpRequest` in the event listener.

Learn more about ajax [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).

Comment: I'm starting to understand it now

Comment: you might want to check if `info.value !== ''` before executing the function to prevent empty data being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it asynchronously.
First, use the  tag to surround the data that you want to post:

```
<form>
...
</form>
```

Tutorial about forms:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

To post form asynchronously, you can use jquery or js. The simple and quick way is jquery. Here is a link to the documentation:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

There is an example at the end of the page of the jquery post doc's page, that explains how to use it, and basically do the thing that you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the link

Comment: @MichelleWNIAP If it helped you, please upvote and check this comment as an answer.

Comment: Don't have enough reputation